# How can I define multiple requirement files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

How can I do define multiple requirements files in my `requirements.txt` file.

```
-r base.txt
-r test.txt
```

The current behavior is that `pip` only installs packages from `test.txt`. I'd expect pip to install packages found in both `base.txt` and `test.txt`. I could have sworn I've seen someone do this in the past, but I can't find any examples.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest `pip`? `pip install -U pip`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`pip` accepts multiple `-r` arguments:

`pip install -r reqs1.txt -r reqs2.txt`

The help for `pip install` [says](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-r):

> -r, --requirement 
> Install from the given requirements file. This option can be used multiple times.

Comment: The OP seems to be using `-r` multiple times but it doesn't work.  Do you know what the minimum version of `pip` is for it to work?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I was using pip 8.1.1 and python 2.7.8.  I'll see if I have an older pip lying around.

Comment: @JohnZwinck   I tried using pip 7.1.2 and encountered permissions errors because pip was trying to copy files from the system python's site-packges into my virtualenv.  I guess pip's caching was different in 7.1.2.

I couldn't see anything on pip's guthub issues searching for "multiple requirements"; searching for just "requirements" brings up 20 pages of issues :(

So I can't say precisely what version, but at least > 7.1.2.

Comment: Is there any performance gain when we add multiple -r arguments vs run pip install sequentially on a set of requirement files?

Answer (score 36):

You can have one file "include" the other; for example, if you put this in `file2.txt`:

```
-r file1.txt
Django
Flask
etc.
```

Then when you do `pip install -r file2.txt`, it will also install things from `file1.txt`.

I often use this strategy to have a "base" requirements file, and then only specify those things that are required at each stage (development, testing, staging, production, etc.)

Comment: How can I accomplish the same thing when I'm installing a locally-created package through its setup.py? e.g. `pip install -e my-package`. When I have multiple requirements files I get this error: "error in my-package setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'-r requi'".

Comment: How do you handle pip freeze with this?

Answer (score 8):

I have many requirements in different directories and solve this problem as:

```sh
sudo find . -name "requirement*" -type f -exec pip3 install -r '{}' ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the contents of all available *requirements.txt* files in this directory in a single "`pip install`" shot, as long as there are no spaces in the directory paths:

```
find -name requirements.txt -printf '--requirement %p ' | 
  xargs --no-run-if-empty pip install
```